# Is there anything I can do as a passenger to shorten the time between when the check-in counter opens and my flight lands at its destination?

Tags: air-travel, tips-and-tricks, check-in

If I myself am clearing check-in, boarding, and disembarking fairly quickly, is there anything else I can do to help make these processes go smoother and faster?

Comment: Based on the confusion about Berwyn's [answer](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/73386/42899), can you clarify whether you are referring to making it faster for you personally, or in a broader sense of helping the flow for the entire aircraft so it's better for everyone. Personally, I took the 2nd meaning, while Berwin took the 1st, and both, without clarification, are perfectly reasonable perspectives based on current wording.

Comment: @FreeMan I see your point, but that would seem to be off-topic for travel.SE and to belong in aviation.SE maybe?

Comment: @Berwyn - I think the Aviation folks would tend to send it back over here, since it's a pax issue.

Answer (score 6):

This is a bit of a broad question but I'll have a go.

Actions that may shorten check-in to arrival:

- Check-in online
- Print or collect boarding pass on mobile
- Carry hand
  luggage only - This and above will help ensure you do not need to
  visit a check-in or bag-drop desk or wait for luggage on arrival
- Qualify for fast track security -
  This requires becoming a high status frequent flyer or paying for
  business class or above. Alternatively, register for trusted
  traveller programmes such as Nexus, pre-check, Global Entry
- Choose
  seating near to most likely exit door
- Travel business class or first class - Sometimes other passengers are held back in order to allow premium class travellers to deboard earlier
- Investigate departing airport
  and terminal - In some cases you may enter at faster checkpoints or
  alternate terminals leading to the same airside lounge area
- Investigate arrival airport and terminal - There may be automated
  passport kiosks accessible to a subset of passengers. You may need to
  register to use these.
- Investigate premium arrival services - Some
  airports allow you to pay to be met at the aircraft and escorted
  through arrival procedures
- Achieve ultra-high frequent flyer status on operating airline - in some cases special service staff will pick you up or deliver you to the aircraft by car

Comment: The question appears to be asking about the influence a passenger can exert on the progress of the flight itself. For example, your advice about premium arrival services has no impact on the time at which the flight lands.

Comment: @phoog If the OP meant speeding up the flight, why would they ask about improving the process of disembarking? I answered the question as to what I thought the OP really meant, rather than precise wording in the title. Perhaps you can supply an alternate answer and the OP can choose?